# Core Plot: Updating position of y axis

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-plot

Im currently doing a real time plot where I generate data every second. The problem I'm running into is that after about 15 seconds or so, because of how I have my xRange set, my plot begins to move/scroll automatically, which is an intentional effect, however my y axis seems to be rooted at the origin and quickly falls off screen. How would I either set the position to be rooted at the center of the view constantly, or what property do I need to update in order for the Y axis to also move?

I've looked through them all but I don't see anything obvious, or anything that seems to apply based on the included definitions/help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I happened to find the answer in an old google groups thread, so I will post it here as a confirmation of it working in Core Plot 1.0, and since this is a bit more organized/searchable place.

When you're initializing the plot, you want to set the axis constraint as follows.

```
axisSet.yAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
```